# nacos inside kubernetes failed to connect to the mysql when using endpoints replacing the specific ip

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deploy v2.2.3 nacos in kubernetes connecting the external v5.7 mysql. Everything works well until I try to use the Endpoints to replace the specific mysql address written in the StatefulSet.yml:

```
   - name: MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST
     value: outside-mysql-svc    #works well if these two values are '192.168.100.97' and '3306'
   - name: MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT
     value: outside-mysql-svc
```

The mysql service and endpoints:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: outside-mysql-svc                            
  namespace: dev
spec:
  ports:
    - name: out-mysql-port                             
      port: 3307                                                
      protocol: TCP                                             
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: outside-mysql-svc                           
  namespace: dev
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.100.97                                
    ports:
      - port: 3307                                                  
        name: out-mysql-port                         
        protocol: TCP
```

The nacos error message is 'No DataSource set'. I wonder why the endpoints won't work?

I check the nacos image code https://github.com/nacos-group/nacos-docker/tree/v2.2.3, in the application.properties
, it shows that:

```
db.url.0=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST}:${MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT:3306}/${MYSQL_SERVICE_DB_NAME}?${MYSQL_SERVICE_DB_PARAM:characterEncoding=utf8&connectTimeout=1000&socketTimeout=3000&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false}
```

I think it is because the ${MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST} and ${MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT:3306} are divided, so the endpoints doesn't work unless these two variables can be combined in one variable?